# make objects and fields dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

instead of using getParameterByName('Field', PostData) (PostData == $('form').serialize();)

I would like to write PostData.Field, how can i do that with javascript?

Comment: Is there a good reason *not* to use a selector such as `$('input[name=Field]').val()`?

Comment: ATM that is getting me the value of the first radio box and not what is currently selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own extension to return an object like you want, here's what that looks like:

```
jQuery.fn.MakeIntoFields = function() {
  var arr = this.serializeArray();
  var props = {};
  $.each(arr, function(i, f) {
    props[f.name] = f.value;
  });
  return props;
};
```

You'd call it by doing this:

```
var PostData = $("form").MakeIntoFields();
```

Then you could access the values with dot notation like you want:

```
PostData.fieldNameHere
//or...
PostData["fieldNameHere"]
```

[You can see this working against a demo `<form>` here](http://jsfiddle.net/DJVdE/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
PostData = {
  field: $('input[name=Field]').val(),
  otherData: 'customdata'
};
```

Comment: No i mean obj = MakeIntoFields(PostData);
obj.FieldName